# GZIP Compression for all HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess, gzip

I'm trying to GZIP compression in `.htaccess` file, I have tested the HTML pages and they are all being compressed for some reason it won't compress my `javascripts` and `css` files?

Does anyone know the code to add in the `htaccess` file to ensure all elements are compressed in the website?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're also including js and css file extensions?

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  # filetypes to cover
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

[Source](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html)

Alternatively:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    #The following line is enough for .js and .css
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom_xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php application/x-httpd-fastphp text/html     
    #The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
</IfModule>
```

See [here for further information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846376/gzip-compression-through-htaccess-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried both methods and it only gzips the HTML pages. The CSS and JS files still don't gzip